# Sorting a tuple list by the Counter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, tuples

I have read and tried to implement suggestions from around Stack Overflow.

In Python 3.6+ I have a list of tuples that looks something like this:

```
tuple_list=[(a=3,b=gt,c=434),(a=4,b=lodf,c=We),(a=3,b=gt,c=434)]
```

created by

```
for row in result:    
    tuple_list.append(var_tuple(row['d'], row['f'], row['q']))
```

I want to count the number of duplicates in the list and then sort the list so the number with the highest duplicates is at the top so I used

```
tuple_counter = collections.Counter(tuple(sorted(tup)) for tup in tuple_list)
```

But this returns in error because

```
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

I've also tried this but it doesn't seem to sort by the highest counter.

```
tuple_counter = collections.Counter(tuple_list)
tuple_counter = sorted(tuple_counter, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

As well as this

```
tuple_counter = collections.Counter(tuple_list)
tuple_counter = tuple_counter.most_common()
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You have a syntax error at line 1, i did not down vote, but you should show a valid `tuple_list` we can use

Comment: Wait, why doesn't `tuple_counter.most_common()` work?

Comment: @JaredGoguen because `sorted(tup)` fails *way* before you even get a `tuple_counter`. See my answer.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino ??? that one is instantiated by `collections.Counter(tuple_list)` which doesn't use sorted...

Comment: Are the tuples a custom type (perhaps the class `var_tuple`)? If so, does that class have an equality method?

Comment: @JaredGoguen It's all guess work unless the question is edited, I voted to close

Comment: @JaredGoguen Oh the one at the bottom. Sorry, I thought you were talking about the first one lol. My bad

Comment: @JaredGoguen `most_common` doesn't work for this case because it returns a list of tuples where each tuple is `(element, count)`. That is probably better for OP's usage but we don't know what OP's usage is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## `tuple` contains different `type`s

```
tuple_counter = collections.Counter(tuple(sorted(tup)) for tup in tuple_list)
```

This line errors saying that `int < str` cannot be ordered. before any of this is evaluated, the generator expression must be, and `sorted(tup)` immediately breaks. Why? From the error, I am confident that `tup` contains both integers and strings. You can't sort integers and strings in the same list because you can't compare an integer and a string with `<`. If you have a method of comparing `int`s and `str`s, try `sorted(tup, key = function)` with your function to order `int`s and `str`s.

Since you want to count by the number of occurrences, try this:

```
sorted_tuples = sorted(tuple_list, key = tuple_list.count)
```

This sorts the tuples using the counter function of `tuple_list` as a key. If you want to sort descending, do `sorted(tuple_list, key = tuple_list.count, reversed = True)`.